# html elements in jquery each return value

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have an issue trying to display html elements e.g. img, ul, etc when looping through the array.

```
$.each(data[0], function(i, dataa) {
    if(i == 'images') {
        $.each(data[0].images, function(x, datab) {
            $('.g').append('<tr><td>'+datab.imgid+'</td></tr>');
        });
    } else if(i == 'desc') {
        $('.g').append('<tr><td><label>' + i + ' : </label></td>' + '<td>' + dataa + '</td></tr>');
    } else {
        $('.g').append('<tr><td><label>' + i + ' : </label></td>' + '<td><input type="text" name="' + i + '" id="' + i + '" value="' + dataa + '" ></td></tr>');
    }
});
```

the following is adding images to the array:

```
foreach($_FILES['uploadsell1'][tmp_name] as $key => $value) {
    if($_FILES['uploadsell1'][tmp_name][$key] != null) {
        $filename = $_FILES['uploadsell1'][name][$key];
        $tempname = $_FILES['uploadsell1'][tmp_name][$key];
        copy($tempname, 'images/ads/tempads/'.$filename);

        $df[]["imgid"] = "<img src='/images/ads/tempads/".$filename."' height='80' width='100' />";
    }
}


$row['images'] = $df;                       
echo '['.json_encode($row).']';
```

Data posted in fields work fine. Its just when html elements are included does it mess up. Is there any other way round this?

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is missing some information, like : what is the flow? what is $row. I see "input" fields, but no reference to them (for submission?). What do you mean by "html elements are included"? What do you mean "it mess up" - what do you see?

Comment: I think I got it - data is somehting like `[{ images : [ { imgid : "<img ... " } ] } ]` , that's why you have data[0]. The flow is `I am showing a list of files in a table where their content is editable. But when the files have HTML content, it is messed up`. I will try to answer the question as if I understood it correctly. Please correct me if not.

Comment: I'm sorry for not including the whole code to make more sense. Yeah your on the right track. I came up with a solution like this [{ images : [ { imgid : "/images/..." } ] } ]...I then do this '<img src='+datab.imgid'+ '/>' to handle the response. I was just wondering is there not a way you could do something like datab.imgid.html()

Comment: personally I like the solution `imgid: "/images"` better. I don't like HTML snippets in JSON, I think it's against the basic concept. I also think you should check out [JSRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender). I tried your code, couldn't see any problem. check it out at [My site](http://www.mograbi.info/stackoverflow/question_12313972/main.php). By the way, you don't need to use `..html()` at all..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Try modifying your code from

`$('.g').append('<tr><td>'+datab.imgid+'</td></tr>');`

to

`$('.g').append( $('<tr/>').append($('<td/>').append($("<img/>").attr("src", datab.imgid).attr("width",datab.width).attr("height",datab.height))));`

in the client side. 
In the server side you need to do something like

`$df = array ( array("src" => 'images.jpg', 'height' => '80', 'width' => '100') );`

which means to breakdown the tag and detail all the attributes you want to give the tag in the HTML. 
please note you can easily get a more generic way if you do something like

`$df = array ( array("src" => 'images.jpg', "attrs" => array('height' => '80', 'width' => '100')) );`

and then in javascript loop through "attrs" as well.

You might want to consider something along the line of stating CSS instead of tag attributes. and then the JavaScript should call [`css(key,value)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead of `attr(key,value)` as CSS is more powerful.

But the idea is if you want to construct the following HTML

`<img src="my_src.jpg" height="100" width="80"/>`

then you JavaScript should look like this

`$("<img/>").attr("src","my_src.jpg").attr("height","100").attr("width","80")`

You can check out my running example at [my site](http://www.mograbi.info/stackoverflow/question_12313972/main.php).

If I misunderstood your question or if you see any problem with my answer, please let me know so I will edit it.

Comment: i had to settle with the earlier solution of $df[]["imgid"] = "<img src='/images/ads/tempads/".$filename."' height='80' width='80'. it works i guess. The broader question of returning html tags in general is causing an issue in that I only see the end tags e.g </b> and not <b> also, what could be causing this?